# How to exclude ® ™ signs in URL

Tags: magento2, url, seo, automation

**We are having a URL issues**

For Example -

If Title = Bose® SoundLink™ 10 Wireless Music System

Then URL = bose-soundlink-10-wireless-music-system

**But in our new website URL is - boser-soundlinktm-10-wireless-music-system**

---

We need Bose® = *bose* and SoundLink™ = *soundlink*

**How to exclude ® ™ signs in URL**

Please suggest!

Thanks

Comment: This is a product url? Are you importing those from mass import?

Comment: Yes, they are coming from POS (Software)

Comment: Check this - https://perishablepress.com/stop-using-unsafe-characters-in-urls/ Can we do the same in Magento 2

Answer (score 0):

```
$product_url = $product->getProductUrl();

$replace = array(' ','!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '_', '.','(', ')', '=', '+', '?','®', '/', '<', '>', '|', '`', '~','™');

$updated_product_url = strtolower(str_replace($replace, '-', trim($product_url)));
```

You need to do this process in the proper steps. Then, You can use this **$updated_product_url** variable as your product url.

Comment: Do we have to update this in every page?